# Asymptotics of list size in Robertson-Seymour theorem

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, topological-graph-theory, graph-minors, obstruction-theory

A planar graph cannot have $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ as minors. Robertson-Seymour theorem generalizes this by stating for every genus $g$ there is a finite list of forbidden minor graphs that are obstructions that prevent the graph from being genus $g$. Is there any result on the size of the list? Is it linear in $g$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not linear in the genus; it is at least exponential in $g$. See for example this [answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8876/forbidden-minors-for-bounded-genus-graphs) by David Eppstein.

Comment: i dont see a reference for 'at least'.

Comment: As Eppstein mentions, if you take a graph which consists of exactly $g+1$ blocks, each of which is a $K_5$ or a $K_{3,3}$, then this will be an excluded minor for embedding in a surface of genus $g$.  There are obviously at least $2^{g+1}$ such graphs.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that [this paper by Djidjev and Reif](https://users.cs.duke.edu/~reif/paper/djidjev/genus.pdf) establishes an upper bound of $\exp(O(g)!)$ for the number of minimal forbidden minors.

Djidjev, Hristo, and John Reif. "An efficient algorithm for the genus problem with explicit construction of forbidden subgraphs." Proceedings of the twenty-third annual ACM symposium on Theory of computing. ACM, 1991.